# Need to be able to pull a specific row in an array corresponding to the product the user selects

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am a beginner programmer who needs help with a small project website.

I have a created a shop and have stored some products in a mysql database. I have use a foreach loop to loop through the data and print out each relevant into styled Divs. The data is added into a new array before the foreach loop.

```
$sql = "SELECT name, description, price, image FROM shop";
    $result = $DBConn->query($sql);
 $data = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;

    foreach($data as $v){
  ?>
        <div class="innerbox">
             <div class="imagebox"><img src="<?php echo $v['image'];?>" /></div>  
            div class="namebox"><?php echo $v["name"];?></div>
            <div class="pricebox">£<?php echo $v["price"];?></div>

                </div>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
```

Using an onClick function I can make it so when the user clicks within the div, it will direct them to a product page. Here is where I am stuck, How do I make it so the page knows what product the user has clicked, and pull only the product details in which the user has clicked?

I assume it would need to be a loop of some kind to check what the ID contained within the div that the user has clicked using javascript?

Sorry for the poor formatting, rather new to this.

Edits**

```
<div id="productimage">
                    <div class="productinner"><img src="<?php echo $v['image'];?>" /></div>
                </div>
                <div id="productdescription"><?php echo $v["description"];?></div>
                <div id="videobox"><?php echo $v["price"];?></div>
<?php
```

Do I need this code on the product page? or?

```
$sql = "SELECT name, description, price, image FROM shop";
    $result = $DBConn->query($sql);
 $data = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row; // Adds each row to a new array
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set data-id attribute on the div:

```
    <div class="innerbox" data-id="<?php echo $v['id']; ?>">
         <div class="imagebox"><img src="<?php echo $v['image'];?>" /></div>  
        div class="namebox"><?php echo $v["name"];?></div>
        <div class="pricebox">£<?php echo $v["price"];?></div>

    </div>
```

using jQuery you can easily get the data:

```
$('.innerbox').click(function() {
    window.location.href = "product.php?id=" + $(this).data('id');
});
```

and in php you can access id using `$_GET['id']`

```
$sql = "SELECT name, description, price, image FROM shop WHERE id = " . intval($_GET['id']);
```

Comment: Still Not sure how this attribute works. I have a seperate php page which has similar styled divs. I'll post edit it into the question.

Comment: @Elrin You mean that you have another page that show the product? then use that data value in query string you will have id in $_GET array.

Comment: Ahh I see! Let me try it and I'll get back to you!

Comment: First problem, it's not directing the user to the productpage.php when I try to click one of the divs containing a product, and I'm getting an Undefined index: id  on the product page but it is displaying 1 of the products and not trying to display all of them at once which it was doing before.